# Difference between /bin/bash and /bin/sh and calling the script directly

Tags: bash

This is the content of my script

```
#!/bin/bash
# test.sh
# Note: Set permissions on this script to 555 or 755,
# then call it with ./test.sh or sh ./test.sh.
echo
echo "This line appears ONCE in the script, yet it keeps echoing."
echo "The PID of this instance of the script is still $$."
# Demonstrates that a subshell is not forked off.
echo "==================== Hit Ctl-C to exit ===================="
sleep 1
exec $0 # Spawns another instance of this same script
#+ that replaces the previous one.
echo "This line will never echo!" # Why not?
exit 99 # Will not exit here!
# Exit code will not be 99!
```

And this is the output when I run the script using /bin/bash

```
[user@localhost ~]$ /bin/bash test.sh 

This line appears ONCE in the script, yet it keeps echoing.
The PID of this instance of the script is still 4872.
==================== Hit Ctl-C to exit ====================
test.sh: line 11: exec: test.sh: not found
```

This is the output when I run the script using /bin/sh

```
[user@localhost ~]$ /bin/sh ./test.sh 

This line appears ONCE in the script, yet it keeps echoing.
The PID of this instance of the script is still 4934.
==================== Hit Ctl-C to exit ====================

This line appears ONCE in the script, yet it keeps echoing.
The PID of this instance of the script is still 4934.

==================== Hit Ctl-C to exit ====================
```

I had to use Ctl-C to stop this.

Why does the same script behave differently based on different mode of execution. FYI: I had to use Ctl-C which I executed the script like this: `./test.sh`

Comment: For actual differences between Bourne and Bash, there's a whole section in the Bash manual about this topic. This is not one of them, though. Your script is valid in both; for consistency, you may want to change the shebang line to `#!/bin/sh` (or edit comments etc to point to `/bin/bash` instead).

Answer (score 1):

The first time you run this script using `/bin/bash test.sh`. The second time, you run it with `/bin/sh ./test.sh`. Note the difference: `test.sh` vs `./test.sh`.

For whatever reason, the script is unable to spawn a second process running the script, because it's unable to find `test.sh`. (I'm not sure why this is. I'd guess a `PATH` issue, perhaps?) See the below error message:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ /bin/bash test.sh 

This line appears ONCE in the script, yet it keeps echoing.
The PID of this instance of the script is still 4872.
==================== Hit Ctl-C to exit ====================
test.sh: line 11: exec: test.sh: not found
```

The script can't execute `test.sh` because it doesn't know where `test.sh` is; `./test.sh` is a full path to the script, which is findable.

The second time you run it, the child processes spawn happily, because `./test.sh` is found.

Try running: `/bin/bash ./test.sh` and `/bin/sh ./test.sh` and see if there's any difference in the output (shouldn't be).

Answer (score 1):

You get the error `test.sh: not found` because you don't have the current directory in your PATH.

When you run it with `./test.sh`, the pathname is relative and PATH is not consulted, so the command is found.

Note that `/bin/bash ./test.sh` would iterate, and `/bin/sh test.sh` would fail; it is not an issue of the difference between `/bin/bash` and `/bin/sh`.